# Column reference is ambiguous, but only one table in use?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've tried to execute the following query using postgresql with sqlalchemy:

```
        query = text("""
            INSERT INTO similarity (id, %(metric)s)
                 VALUES (:id, :value)
            ON CONFLICT (id)
              DO UPDATE
                    SET %(metric)s = :value
                  WHERE id = :id
        """ % {"metric": metric})
        connection.execute(query, {'metric': metric, 'value': value, 'id': id})
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 7:                   WHERE id = 608220
```

However I only see that I'm using one table (similarity)... So how can this be an ambiguous reference and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Perhaps:   WHERE id = excluded.id

Comment: Please show us the complete, generated statement. It's hard to tell what exactly the problem is when we don't see the SQL statement that gets executed